# How to show a circle symbol only for numbers in input type="tel"

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have input box type of "tel" . If user enter any number it will be masking "99-9999999" this format.

Every thing good as we accepted but i need to show a circle of all the numbers in input box.

Ex:

**..-.......**

We tried lot of methods i can't achieve it anyone please guide me resolve this issue.

**JS:**

```
$(document).delegate('#tinid', 'keyup', function(e) {
        var Textlength = $(this).val();
        var i;
        var text1;
       var reg = new RegExp('^[0-9]$');
        for(i=0; i<Textlength.length;i++)
        {
            //alert(Textlength[i]);
             if(reg.test(Textlength[i])){

               $(Textlength[i]).css('-webkit-text-security','none');
              //alert(true);
             }
             else
             {

           $(Textlength[i]).css('-webkit-text-security','circle');
           //alert(false);
             }
        }   
        if (Textlength.trim().length == 3) {
            $("#claimformns_taxidIA").mask("99-9999999");
            $("#claimformns_taxidIA").attr('type','tel');
        } else {
            $("#claimformns_taxidIA").attr('type','tel');
        }
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<input id="tinid" name=""  class="" type="tel"  value="">
```

Comment: -webkit-text-security: disc;    Try this

Comment: @Ramkee : Change style did not applied ..